# Unable to fetch sqlite record with alphanumeric values

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, hashmap

I am using below code to fetch an sqlite record in my android app. This code fetches numeric values, but doesn't fetch alphanumeric values.

Eg: When "tempno" is 2, the record is fetched, but it doesn't fetch the record when "tempno" is 2A.

All the variables I've used are of "String" data type.

```
public Map<String, Object> getDetails(String tempno) throws SQLException{
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {SOURCE, DESTINATION, ROUTELENGTH, NOTE}, ROUTENO + "=" + tempno, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Am calling below code from another class.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
Map<String, Object> temp = dbAdapt.getDetails(tempno);
```

Below is the error in Logcat

```
  09-26 18:42:52.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2363): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "2A": , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT source, destination, routelength, note FROM route WHERE routeno=2A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to this:

```
public Map<String, Object> getDetails(String tempno) throws SQLException{       
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
  Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {SOURCE, DESTINATION, ROUTELENGTH, NOTE}, ROUTENO + "='" + tempno+"'", null, null, null, null, null); 


//ROUTENO + "='" + tempno+"'",
```

that is a quick&dirty solution but it works. That is not the common way to put values in a sql string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `query`'s parameter substitution instead of your own:

```
public Map<String, Object> getDetails(String tempno) throws SQLException{
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {SOURCE, DESTINATION, ROUTELENGTH, NOTE}, ROUTENO + "= ?", new String[] { tempno }, null, null, null, null);
```